# Editar valor da célula na aba errada

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Galera primeiramente bom dia!

Eu to com um problema, pois fiz um botão de editar o valor de uma certa célula, porém eu meu arquivo tem 10 abas diferentes, e ele está registrando na aba errada, como eu posso fazer para selecionar a aba certa ?

Segue o código abaixo.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

If TxtPrevisto.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Campo Vazio!")
Else
    Range("D2").Value = TxtPrevisto.Text
End If

MetaEHS.LabelEdit = lvwManual

    With MetaEHS


        .SelectedItem.SubItems(3) = TxtPrevisto.Text
        .SelectedItem.SubItems(4) = TxtRealizado.Text


    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Veja como pegar o nome da planilha e declarar uma variável, por exemplo como `ws`, então seu código ficaria `ws.Range("D2").Value = TxtPrevisto.Text`

Comment: Para aprender como fazer no Excel clique em Gravar Macro, selecione a aba correta com o mouse, clique em Parar Gravação e veja o código da Macro que o Excel gravou. Você pode aprender como fazer qualquer coisa no Excel desse modo.